# Git exclude all files that match a name in all folders expect folders named Views

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude all file named Web.config from every folder in my directory
expect when the parent folder is named 'Views'

Ex directory:

```
-Root

  -ApiProject
      -Web.config (should exclude)
      -SomeOther.file (should allow)
      -SubFolder     (should allow)
          -one.file     (should allow)
          -two.file     (should allow)
  -MvcProject
      -Web.config (should exclude)
      -Views
          -Web.config (should allow)
```

I have tried via the below in the .gitignore file, but doesnt seem to be working. The Web.config in the Views folder is not being added

[Ww]eb.config

!**/Views/[Ww]eb.config

Comment: What is not working? Is the file in "Views" also ignored? Or are the files in "MvcProject" and "ApiProject" not ignored? In the later case: Were those files committed before? Showing the result of `git status` might help to understand what is happening.

Comment: Its the Web.config in the Views folder which is not being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
**/[Ww]eb.config
!**/Views/[Ww]eb.config
```

`**/[Ww]eb.config` makes Git ignore files named `Web.config` and `web.config` in any folder, and `!**/Views/[Ww]eb.config` overrides previous pattern to not ignore these files if they are located within `Views` folder.

Also keep in mind that gitignore only works for currently untracked files:

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
>   should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected.

See [How to make Git “forget” about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/7018603)

Comment: This is exactly it. I had just added this before i read your comment. And its working as expected.